# Hydrogen evolution on gold

Tags: electrochemistry

I am working on intercalating an organic compound ( an amine) in another material. This has to be done in acidic medium and thus I am using HCl with gold as the cathode. I am wondering at what voltage the hydrogen may start to come out because of the reduction of H+ ions since I will have to keep my operating voltage under that one.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Consider voltammetric curves for both electrodes. It then gives you the voltage for the given current and vice versa. And also look at overpotential of hydrogen on gold, possibly also for oxygen on anode metal, if applies.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overpotential

Comment: Besides, it is also convenient to subsitute HCl with H$_2$SO$_4$, you may inadvertingly  oxidize the chlorine anion.